# "Error: Failed to install package from local : file name conversion problem -- name too long ?" when using remotes::install

Tags: r, rscript

I want to install a R package that I am working on and which is located in a local folder.

I am using "Rscript start2.R" in the VScode terminal to start my script.

**This is part of "start2.R":**

``` install.packages("remotes", repos = "``http://cran.us.r-project.org``") ```
`library(remotes)`
`#remove.packages("openeocubes")`
`remotes::install_local('./',dependencies=TRUE, force=TRUE,lib="D:/rpacks")`

`library(openeocubes,lib.loc="D:/rpacks")`

Installing remotes works but then I get this Error:

**"Error: Failed to install 'openeocubes' from local:**
**file name conversion problem -- name too long?**
**Execution halted"**

openeocubes is the package I am working on which I have forked from GitHub. **It requires R (>= 4.3.0)**

How can I fix this error so I can see if the changes I have made to the package work ?

I expected the package to be installed correctly.
When I am installing the same package in a docker image I don't get that error but parsing errors instead, because there are some mistakes in my code. Unfortunately restarting and rebuilding the image takes over 5 min every time I make fixes and when I want to test them.

### the code in dockerfile: (the package is in ./)

`COPY ./ /opt/dockerfiles/ RUN Rscript -e "remove.packages('openeocubes')" RUN Rscript -e "remotes::install_local('/opt/dockerfiles',dependencies=TRUE)"`